# Do adblocker block the url containg affiliate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, adblock

I have an rails application. In which while calling affilaite controller makes a url /affilaite/ which is getting blocked by adblocker. 
So do adblocker blocks the url containg affiliate or there is some other reason due to which this url is getting blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look into [this](https://easylist.to/easylist/easylist.txt) file. It's EasyList file, one of the AdBlock's lists, which helps to determine, whether a link (html element, etc..) should be blocked. It's actually contains parts of the suspicious objects some of them are with `affiliate` word in it. Something like:

```
-affiliate-link.
-affiliates/img_
```

You can look through this file and determine, whether your link contains some of these parts and therefore blocked. If not, then you need to investigate it in other AdBlock's lists.

Comment: I have checked the list. in this there are many affiliate urls similar to mine getting blocked. But does adblocker blocks only the url is the above list or it blocks all similar urls. Ex:- given in list url bet365.com/affiliate/.   My url  abc.net/app/affiliate/overview.  So should i draw a conclusion that my url will also get blocked

Comment: no, it shouldn't. your link should match the pattern described in the file. I see that AdBlock blocks anything containing `.net/affiliate/`, seems the closest to your example